# How to check serializability

Tags: transactions, database

I am practicing for my end-semester exams and this piece of question is bugging me a lot. We have two database transactions T1 and T2 accessing an object X.

```
T1:W(X), T2:R(X), T1:W(X), T2:Abort, T1:Commit
```

The answer given in the solution manual is that this schedule is not serializable. But is think it is equivalent to the serial schedule
    T2: R(X) , T2:Abort, T1: W(X) , T1: W(X) , T(1): Commit.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Source:  Database Management Systems, Ramakrishna & Gehrke 3e.

Answer (score 0):

While checking serializability, one only needs to look at the correctness of transactions which finally commit. So in the case this schedule is serializable. It is equivalent to

T1: W(X) , T1: W(X), T1: Commit.